# Проверка на NaN

Tags: javascript

Почему если ввести не число, оно всё равно проходит проверку на `NaN`?

```
let property = +prompt("Enter a number", "0");

if (property === NaN) {
    alert("Error");
} else if (property > 0) {
    alert(1);
} else if (property < 0) {
    alert(-1);
} else if (property == 0) {
    alert(0);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Согласно спецификации `NaN !== NaN`.

Для проверки нужно использовать либо метод [`isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN), либо [`Number.isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN) либо [`Object.is`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/is)

```js
console.log(NaN === NaN);
console.log(NaN == NaN);
console.log(isNaN(NaN));
console.log(Number.isNaN(NaN));
console.log(Object.is(NaN, NaN));
```